# Why can internet browsers install without admin rights

Tags: browser, admin, rights

So I'm trying to understand admin rights with program files and such and when testing applications I realized that you can install Chrome, Firefox and Opera (haven't tried Safari) without admin rights, Firefox asks you for admin rights but you can just cancel and it will work anyway, I'm pretty sure it's the same deal with Chrome and Opera didn't even ask me anything and just installed. If anyone has a clue as to why, feel free to share! I'm guessing it has something to do with them installing in AppData or something? But then they also create files in Program Files which should require admin privileges.

Thanks in advance!